# Unable to utilise read_excel

Tags: r

I am trying to open an .xlsx file w/ read_excel.
This is the message that I get:

```
library(readxl)
dataset <- read_excel(file.choose())
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘pillar’
```

I tried to install the package but it would not load it.
Any thoughts?

Comment: This looks like an R coding question - you should probably ask it on stack overflow.

Comment: It sounds like the package called `pillar` is not installed. Try `install.packages("pillar")`